# Securely erasing/wiping gRPC/Netty ByteBuf when done?

Tags: netty, grpc, grpc-java

After both receiving and sending sensitive data (using TLS of course), I would like to wipe the information as soon as possible and not wait for the Netty ByteBuf/ByteBuffers to be reused or garbage collected (and reused). How is this best accomplished?

Ideally the solution should be done at a single point in the code, and preferably also work with gRPC when running on top of Netty.

I noticed there's ByteBuf.release(), Cleaner.freeDirectByteBuffer(), PoolArena.destroyChunk(), AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.deallocate() etc, but they all seem difficult to override or replace without modifying Netty itself. Or would it make a nice feature to add to Netty?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for a way to `zero-out` memory after we are done with it. You could write your own `ByteBufAllocator` for this and use it for all the `Channel`s.